# Can a named-pipe client write to multiple instances?

Tags: windows, winapi, named-pipes

After creating multiple instances of a named pipe (using CreateNamedPipe()), I use CreateFile() to form a pipe client.
When the client writes a message to the pipe, only one server instance gets it.

Is there a way for the client to write a message to all instances?

Comment: You want a mailslot for broadcast functionality.

Comment: What I want is health and happiness. This is just a question on the internets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a client connects to an instance of a named pipe, the manner in which the operating system chooses which server instance to make the connection to is undocumented, as far as I know. However, empirically it appears to be done on a round robin basis.

If you are prepared to rely on undocumented behaviour which may change with service packs and QFE patches, your client can keep closing its pipe handle and calling CreateFile again to get a new one - each time it will attach to a new server instance of the pipe. However, there is a problem with this in that the client would not know when to stop. I suppose you could invent some mechanism involving a response from the server to break the loop but it is far from satisfactory. This isn't what named pipes were designed for.

The real purpose of multiple server instances of a pipe is to enable pipe servers to handle multiple clients concurrently. Usually, the same server process manages all the instances.

You really want to turn things around: what you think of as your client should be the server, and should create and manage the pipe. Processes which want notification would then connect as clients of the named pipe. This is a pattern which can be implemented quite easily using WCF, with a duplex contract and the NetNamedPipeBinding, if that's an option.

Answer (score 1):

No, a pipe has two ends.  Loop through the pipes.  A mailslot supports broadcasts but delivery isn't guarantee.

Comment: How can I loop through all existing pipes created with a given name?

Comment: Erm, store them in a HANDLE[] for example.  Btw, very unusual for a client to manage multiple pipes.  Usually it is a server.  I might be missing something in your question.

Comment: Scenario is: several apps want to be notified when new messages arrive. Each create an instance of the same pipe, using CreateNamedPipe(). Thus they are all 'pipe servers'. The messages are provided by the writing side, which only knows the pipe-name.

Comment: Okay, that's what I meant.  Yes, just iterate the pipes that you are connected to and WriteFile() each of them.

Comment: So question remains: how the writing app (the 'pipe client') can iterate the instances that currently exist, where it only knows the pipe's name?

Comment: Erm, you have to *open* the pipe before you can write to it.  There can only be a *single* instance of a pipe with a specific name.  There is no API to enumerate pipes by name.

Comment: Well, unless you specify FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE, you can create multiple instances of the same pipe in different apps. It seems that such multiple instances do more harm than good, since there is no way to tell between them (and no way to send them all). So the real question is: what such multiple-instances are good for?

Comment: I give up, trying to answer your question is like trying to nail jelly to the wall.  Good luck.

Comment: @Hans: Actually the OP is right - you **can** have multiple instances of a pipe with a specific name. Each has a client and a server end, and the clients and servers can all be different processes. That's why named pipes are potentially vulnerable to squatting exploits, and it's why `FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE` was introduced to counter this vulnerability.